# Shading applied only to the first element with foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I want to apply the same shading to multiple rectangles. Here is a MWE of the code I use (for a sample of 3 rectangles):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,textwidth=8.5in,textheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\coordinate(A) at (1.5,4);

\foreach \x in {0,1,2}
\shadedraw [thick, left color=white, right color=black] (A) ++(6*\x,0) rectangle +(1,-0.35); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, here is what I get with this code:

[image]

Only the first rectangle is shaded... How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `++` is not a calculation specification but denotes a relative coordinate (which all following relative coordinate specifications are relative to, in contrast to `+`). Compare to `(A) -- ++ (6*\x,0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed rather esoteric but the action `(A) ++(x,y)` is actually counting the `(A)` as a part of the path and what you see is the whole fading strip punched and viewed through 3 holes. Because each of them actually takes `(A)` into account for the fading even though you don't draw anything in between.

You can fix it via `([xshift=6*\x cm]A)` or with calc library syntax `($(A)+(6*\x,0)$)` and so on. As long as you don't modify the path pen you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: I usually don't like to mix canvas and xy coordinates: I'd use either `([shift=(0:6*\x)A)` or more likely `([shift=(A)]6*\x,0)` (the `shift=(A)` part can also be added to the path then).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel why not ?

Comment: If the *x* vector has been changed (say `x=2cm` or `x=(30:1cm)`) then `(6*\x,0)` and `(6*\x cm,0)` will not be the same anymore.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel True but shift would be the same so that is up to OPs liking. I just mean that `(A)` should be inside the coordinate calculation not in the pen movetos. Am I missing your point?

Comment: No, `([xshift=<value> cm]<sth>)` is not the same as `([xshift=(0:<value>)<sth>)`, except when `x=(0:1cm)` (the default). In my eyes, a fundamental difference in TikZ/PGF. But, yes, that doesn't concern OP's problem (which you have identified correctly).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `shift` is not similar to `xshift` one of them processes the coordinate the other one uses `\pgfpointadd`-like mechanism. So if you want a transformation aware shift yes but otherwise it is independent from the transformation which is in certain cases pretty nice because you don't want to convert everything. So the names are similar but functions are quite different. Thanks for spotting it, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate(A) at (1.5,4);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}
    \shadedraw [thick, left color=white, right color=black] (A) ++(6*\x,0) rectangle +(1,-0.35);

    \coordinate(b0) at (-4.5,2);
    \path [draw, thick, left color=white, right color=black] foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,1,2} {(b\x |- b0) ++(6,0) coordinate (b\i) rectangle ++(1,-0.35)};

    \coordinate(C) at (1.5,0);
    \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,1,2}
      \shadedraw [thick, left color=white, right color=black] ([xshift=6*\x cm]C) rectangle +(1,-0.35);

    \coordinate(D) at (1.5,-2);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}
    \path (D) ++(6*\x,0) node [minimum height=3.5mm, minimum width=10mm, inner sep=0pt, anchor=north west, thick, draw, left color=white, right color=black] {};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: play]